# A closed form for the recursion?

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms, recursion

Let $x$ and $y$ be real numbers and $x < y$
 Given the recursion: $m_0 = \frac{x+y}{2}$ and  $m_1 =\frac{m_0+ y}{2}$, so in general, $$m_i = \frac{m_{i-1} + y}{2}$$..

What is $m_{\infty}$? thanks

Comment: You haven't defined $m_\infty$: your definition only defines $m_x$ when $x$ is a natural number. Did you mean to define $m_\infty$ as the limit of $m_n$ as $n \to \infty$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not trying a few terms and see if any pattern becomes obvious. You have
$$m(0)=\frac{1}{2} (x+ y)$$ $$m(1)=\frac{1}{4} (x+3 y)$$ $$m(2)=\frac{1}{8} (x+7 y)$$ $$m(3)=\frac{1}{16} (x+15 y)$$ $$m(4)=\frac{1}{32} (x+31 y)$$ I am sure you see something.

Comment: So that means $m(i)= \frac{x+(2^{i+1}-1)y}{2^{i+1}}$?

Comment: @KenethAdrian. I think you got it !

Comment: thanks claude leibovici, but what is $m(\infty)$ then? since both numerator and denominator has infinity?

Comment: The ratio of the dominant terms seems to be $y$, isn't ?

Comment: i see, thanks so it is $y$?thanks a lot claude

Comment: @KenethAdrian. You are welcome, Sir ! By the way, I do not see why they put restrictions.

Answer (score 4):

$$y-m_i=\frac{y-m_{i-1}}2\qquad y-m_0=\frac{y-x}2$$

Comment: what is $m_\infty$?

Comment: Seriously? Let me suggest to write down $y-m_i$ as a function of $x$, $y$ and $i$, and to stare at the formula one gets for at least 5 seconds. Then see what happens.

Comment: $m_\infty = \frac{y}{2}$?

Comment: Why do you refuse to do what I suggested?

Comment: it's not that i refused, i actually do what your suggesting. thanks

Comment: You did write down $y-m_i$ for every $i$ and you concluded that $m_i\to\frac12y$? Really?

Comment: I guess he's suggesting that $y - m_i$ halves for every increment of $i$.

Comment: so that means $y= m_\infty$

Comment: Tell me. Does it?

Comment: Yes. I would in fact find Did's approach more rigorous and elegant.

Comment: @YiyuanLee. I totally agree.

Answer (score 3):

Show that the sequence is bounded from above (by $y$) and is strictly increasing, hence convergent. Show that for the limit of the sequence, which you seem to denote $m_\infty$, we have $m_\infty=\frac{m_\infty+y}{2}$ and solve for $m_\infty$.